# How to add external scripts and css in latest angular-cli

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-cli

Hey all i am trying to update my angular 2 app from beta to RC5, Mostly done, however now i want to add some external scripts but for some reason they are not getting loaded.

examples include semantic-ui css framework and charts.js angular 2 version

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

but it cannot find them even though they are there, below is the path to the error it gives

```
http://localhost:4200/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js
```

I am using the latest version of angular-cli

`1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` which supports RC5

any help welcomed!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) is how you can integrate 3rd party libs in to your build with angular-cli.

Comment: there is no angular-cli-build.js file

Comment: that tutorial is not related to the webpack version, which you are using

Comment: Did it worked for rc4?

Comment: haven't used it on rc, as i said i am upgrading from beta straight to RC5.

Answer (score 2):

You can put external files in the **assets directory** directory,

and refernce them in src/index.html like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```